# PHP Vertical String to Horizontal String

Tags: php, string, substring

i got the result my for loop : 
FFFF 
AAAA 
TTTT 
EEEE

while mod=4 my loop echo br

but i want result like this : 
FATE 
FATE 
FATE 
FATE

how i do this in php ?
thanks for answers and sorry my english:D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post some of your code. What have you tried? It's difficult to offer advice without more context like

Comment: Please improve the quality of your question while you are here.  Please show how the inout data is structured.  Is it a string? Is it an array of strings?

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of:

- [How to restructure multi-dimensional array with columns as rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45257772/2943403) and
- [Combining array inside multidimensional array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43948739/2943403)

This can be done with foreach loops, but I like the condensed variadic method (PHP 5.6+).
You can research the aforementioned links to see the other techniques if your version isn't high enough or you want something different.

The strings just need to be converted to arrays before rotating, then `imploded()` after rotating.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1e1c74807a7e65052c3c5724226eb63496bed58))

```
$input=['FFFF','AAAA','TTTT','EEEE'];
$rotated=array_map(function(){return implode(func_get_args());},...array_map('str_split',$input));
var_export($rotated);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'FATE',
  1 => 'FATE',
  2 => 'FATE',
  3 => 'FATE',
)
```

---

Here is a less fancy method to achieve the same result:

```
$input=['FFFF','AAAA','TTTT','EEEE'];
$length=strlen($input[0]);
foreach($input as $string){
    for($offset=0; $offset<$length; ++$offset){
        if(!isset($rotated[$offset])){$rotated[$offset]='';}
        $rotated[$offset].=$string[$offset];
    }
}
var_export($rotated);
```

Comment: Good on you typing this up given 0 info from the TO. There is no mention of `array` in the question though - the question relates to a `string`... ?

Comment: The OP's unrotated result is from a for loop.  If it is not from an array, then it is from something acting like an array and is most sensibly converted to an array.

Comment: Thank you mickmakusa and thanks for your comments !

Comment: @user8459759 Other people are disappointed that I answered your low quality question.  Please provide more details in your question.